# responsive css, two diffrent layout when same height of device and different width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I have a web page which has a different layout for iMac and iPod, but unfortunately, iPod and iMac have the same resolution of 1024px height. now when my CSS renders it selects the iPod CSS in iMac how can I resolve this problem?

I am making collapsed bootstrap menu via CSS media query but it also collapse my menu in iMac and I only want it in iPod.

[image]

> iMac CSS

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 2560px) and (min-device-height: 1440px) {
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
}

    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: none !important;
    }

.navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
    display: none !important;
}

.navbar-header {
    float: left !important;
} }
```

> iPod CSS

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (min-device-height: 1024px) {
/* -- Responsive navbar */
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none;
}

    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
        display: block;
    }

.navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}

.navbar-header {
    float: none;
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rarely see `(min-device-height)` in media queries these days. You should be fine just declaring the width. Actually, almost all media queries these days are `(min-width: __px)` or `(max-width: __px)`.

Basically, you're overcomplicating it. Try switching your media queries to:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 2560px) {}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}
```

I'd also recommend adjusting the `min-width` value to something smaller. That desktop media query would only trigger if someone was on a 27" iMac with their browser in full screen. You might want your desktop site to start at `1280px` or something else.

Comment: hey it's not worked for me, please see this link, https://www.dropbox.com/s/6lzkfznau0wlz5n/Screenshot%202017-02-16%2000.42.36.png?dl=0

Comment: Set it to `(max-width: 768px)`. Since you declared `min-width`, and desktop will pretty much always be more than `768px`, it's calling that media query on the wrong window size.

Comment: Glad to hear! Good luck with the rest of the project.